Flutter Firebase Firestore Methods Not Working After Recent Update
My Flutter app that heavily relies on Firebase for various functionalities, particularly Firestore. Everything was working smoothly until yesterday when I noticed that some Firestore methods, such as update and set, are not functioning as expected.
I haven't made any changes to my app's code recently, so I'm puzzled as to why these issues are arising suddenly. I've tried adding multiple error handling mechanisms in all the relevant functions, but they don't provide any useful insights. For instance, when attempting to save a user message to Firebase, I receive the confirmation log '1227 User message saved to Firebase', but the corresponding bot message doesn't get saved ('1227 Bot message saved to Firebase' is missing).
Here is an example
I've double-checked my Firestore rules, ensured that the document paths are correct, and even relaxed the rules temporarily for testing purposes, but the problem persists. Additionally, there are no errors being caught during the Firestore write operations.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
